# UI Router update parent view from child

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to using Angular UI Router and I seem to be having difficulty being able to update a parent view from it's child view.

I have the following HTML structure (restructured for easier reading, obviously views are in separate html files).

```
<div ui-view="main">
    { main content }
    <div ui-view="tab">
        { tabbed content }
    </div>
</div>
```

Inside `tab` I have the following sref:

`<span ui-sref="silverstone.platforms.view({_id: platform._id})">{{platform.name}}</span>`

And here are my states: (I'm using webpack, hence `require`)

```
$stateProvider
    .state('silverstone', {
        url: '/silverstone',
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'SilverstoneCtrl',
                template: require('./templates/index.html')
            }
        }
    });

$stateProvider
    .state('silverstone.platforms', {
        url: '/platforms',
        views: {
            'tab': {
                controller: 'SilverstoneCtrl',
                template: require('./templates/platforms.html')
            }
        }
    });

$stateProvider
    .state('silverstone.platforms.view', {
        url: '/:_id',
        views: {
            'main': {
                controller: 'SilverstoneCtrl',
                template: require('./templates/platform-view.html')
            }
        }
    });
```

When the above sref is clicked, the "main" view needs to be updated. The URL is updating but the views aren't...?

Comment: You should us ui-view directive not ng-view

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh typo :)

Comment: and for template, use `templateUrl` and put your template url, don't use require

Comment: @soroushgholamzadeh i'm using webpack.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing `@` in my silverstone.platforms.view state to explicitly address the parent view.

```
$stateProvider
        .state('silverstone.platforms.view', {
            url: '/:_id',
            views: {
                'main@': {
                    controller: 'SilverstoneCtrl',
                    template: require('./templates/platform-view.html')
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reload: true` parameter in yout `ui-sref` links like this.

```
ui-sref="silverstone.platforms.view({_id: platform._id})" ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}"
```

Edit:
Maybe your problem are caused by nested states combined with flat template structure.
Other solution may be to properly nest your templates, as states.
For example we have states `app` and `app.substate`, then we have two templates for both states. Tempalte of `app` state contains `ui-view` directive. (that means every state contains new `ui-view` directive for injecting of substate template). States are nested by default, this would represent appropriately nested templates.

Comment: I'm afraid that just seems to reload the "tab" view and doesn't change "main".